# button images visibility based on the checkboxlist items

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkboxlist control with 9 button images.
I need it such that if user check on the checkbox item, respective button images will be shown... Total number of checks == 3..

for e.g. (for all images button tat contains the privileges being checked, visibility will be set to true)

ALL THIS MUST BE DONE WITHOUT ANY BUTTON CLICKS

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
    AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Privilege 1">Dining</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Privilege 2">Travel</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Privilege 3">Shopping</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
<table cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="80px" 
                Width="120px" ImageUrl="imageurl" ToolTip="image" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="80px" 
                Width="120px" ImageUrl="imageurl" ToolTip="image" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="80px" 
                Width="120px" ImageUrl="imageurlg" ToolTip="image" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code behind C#

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListItem listItem in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected == true)
        {
            //Just to check which item is being checked
            //However, it only returns one item at a time
            Label1.Text = ", " + listItem.Text;
        }
    }

    //list of privileges
    string[] privilege = { "Privilege 1", "Privilege 2", "Privilege 3", "Privilege 4", "Privilege 5", "Privilege 6", "Privilege 7" };

    ImageButton[] Privilege1 = { ImageButton1, ImageButton5, ImageButton6, ImageButton7, ImageButton8 };
         ........

     if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue == privilege[i])
        {
           //set the visibility of respective button images with this privileges to be true 
        }
}
```

How to go about doing it?? pls helppp....

Comment: If javascript is an option then I'd recommend JQuery on the client side to take care of this for you. I'm confused though how you can have both ASP.NET and asp class tagged on the same question?

Comment: Please remove classic asp tag, it's not classic asp :)

Comment: I've approved your edit @ShadowStorm, but really _"I cannot answer - so it needs to be removed"_ - is that quite what you meant to say? (If we removed all the things _I_ can't answer there'd be hardly anything left...)

Comment: No I never meant that. I answer Classic ASP questions, so I clicked on the cASP tag hoping to get cASP related questions and I got your .NET question, which I cannot answer - hence asking for the tag to be removed

Comment: I used to do it too, until I got told off - no I'm passing my experiences :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is:
1) Set all the Image button's visibility to false by default (i.e. they all start off invisible as no check-box item is selected).

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="80px" Width="120px"    ImageUrl="imageurl" ToolTip="image" Visible="False"/>
```

2) In the code-behind make sure you reference System.Linq. The following does the bit of making the image buttons visible depending on which items are selected (place the constants in a more central spot of course):

```
 public void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            const string PRIVILAGE1 = "Privilege 1";
            const string PRIVILAGE2 = "Privilege 2";
            const string PRIVILAGE3 = "Privilege 3";

            var checkBoxList = sender as CheckBoxList;
            if (checkBoxList == null) return;
            var selectedItems = checkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected).ToList();

            if (!selectedItems.Any()) return;
            ImageButton1.Visible = selectedItems.Any(x => x.Value.Equals(PRIVILAGE1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            ImageButton2.Visible = selectedItems.Any(x => x.Value.Equals(PRIVILAGE2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            ImageButton3.Visible = selectedItems.Any(x => x.Value.Equals(PRIVILAGE3, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```